# Why $\mathbb{E}_{(x, y) \sim \mathcal{D}}[f] = \mathbb{E}_{x \sim \mathcal{D}_{X}}[\mathbb{E}_{y \sim \mathcal{D}_{Y|x}}[f|X=x]]$

Tags: bayesian, conditional-probability, expected-value

I found this equality on p.6 in this [document](https://www.cs.huji.ac.il/%7Eshais/UnderstandingMachineLearning/MLbookSol.pdf) proving that Bayes Predictor is optimal (i.e. it achieves the minimal generalization risk) amongst al hypotheses:

$$
\mathbb{E}_{(x, y) \sim \mathcal{D}}[\mathbb{1}_{[f_{\mathcal{D}}(x) \ne y]}] = \mathbb{E}_{x \sim \mathcal{D}_{X}}[\mathbb{E}_{y \sim \mathcal{D}_{Y|x}}[\mathbb{1}_{[f_{\mathcal{D}}(x) \ne y]}|X=x]]
$$

Where $f$ is defined by:

$f_{\mathcal{D}(x)}=\begin{cases}1\text{ if } \mathbb{P}[y=1|x]\ge1/2\\0\text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$

The author suggests to use the law of total expectation to derive that equality. However I can see that this law concerns only the conditional probability and doesn't (at least directly) mention the joint probability distribution. So how I can apply the law to achieve that result?

Comment: Doesn't this notation use "$\mathcal D$" for the joint probability?  It appears once on the left hand side and twice on the right.